# How to subdivide and smooth top surface of wing but keep hard edges

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am trying to create a smooth top surface on a wing profile.  As it is it is currently too faceted.
[image: Wing Section]I want to produce a mesh for export to print and as it is the section has 'ribs' rather that being smooth.  I wish to retain the straight leading edges and trailing edges as well as the flat ends.
Can you assist?

Comment: You tried adding a crease to the edges you want to keep sharp?

Comment: It tended to distort other bits.  Have done it the long way and subdivided lines and added new edges... Tedious but worked.